# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: (Reason: CORS request failed). in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cors

I am new in angularjs, integrating paytm wallet in my web app. when i am sending request paytm server from my angular js function , it is showing this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/processTransaction?orderid=data.ORDER_ID. (Reason: CORS request failed).

here is my function

```
function sendDataToPaytm(data)
{
    var defer = $q.defer();
    console.log(data);

    $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] =  "*";
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE";
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept";
    console.log($http);
    console.log();

    var url = 'https://pguat.paytm.com/oltp-web/processTransaction?orderid=data.ORDER_ID';
    $http.post(url, data, headers)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        defer.resolve([status, data]);
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
        //console.log("Error in getting sellers info");
        defer.resolve([status, data]);
    });

    return defer.promise;
}
```

please help me to solve this

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I am also the same issue. It seems like somehow we need to configure IP of the testing system on paytm business site.

Answer (score 0):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is a response header that has to be set server side. That is, if the respective server doesn't send this header, the browser prevents you from requesting information from this server due to cross server (domain, subdomain and protocol) infringement.

It would allow requests only if the originating page was served by the same server (domain, subdomain and protocol).

Comment: Paytm server is not in our control. The calling server or calling client only needs to do some modification on there side in order to avoid this.